How to remove the secure textfield added for preventing the screenshot on window in iOS
To prevent user taking screenshot of the application, I have added a secure textfield to the window. Below is the code for achieving this:
extension UIWindow {
    func makeSecure() {
        let field = UITextField()
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: field.frame.self.width, height: field.frame.self.height))
        field.isSecureTextEntry = true
        self.addSubview(field)
        self.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(field.layer)
        field.layer.sublayers?.last!.addSublayer(self.layer)
        field.leftView = view
        field.leftViewMode = .always
    }
}

As per the requirement, based on a boolean this feature can be enabled or disabled. Here I am facing the challenge of removing the added textfield to disable this feature.
How can I achieve this?

Um?  Just don't add it if the boolean is set?

Keep a refernce on it, so you can remove it?

The boolean that decide whether to add the field or not changes on the go. So once its added, when the boolean changes to No, I need to remove it. I have set a tag for the texfield and tried to remove using the tag. But that didn't work.

Your problem is this is an extension on UIWindow so it can't add stored properties. Move this code to a class so that it can store a reference to the view you create.  Pass the window to the function rather than using self. However, because this approach is pretty hacky, I am not sure you are going to be able to successfully remove the sub layer you have added. Perhaps just toggling the isSecureTextEntry will be enough.
